# Facebook SDK 3.0 permissions array for FBSession holds wrong permissions

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, sdk, permissions

With Facebook sdk 3.1  I want to make sure that the app has the "publish_stream" right just before i send the post request.

The problem is [FBSession.activeSession.permissions indexOfObject:@"publish_stream"] never return NSNotFound even if the user chooses allow none during login.This causes a problem naturally because i assume that i have the right to send the post but it returns HTTP status code 403 since i do not have the required right actually.

IS is a bug or is there another way to check the permissions of the active session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook confirmed that it is a bug in iOS SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/111727002307769

The bug still remains in iOS SDK 3.1

A workaround is to check permissons using API call `/me/permissions` as Igy proposed.

Comment: thank you i rely on the the result of /me/permissions but it is not elegant to send and aditional request each time you want to make a post or something.USer could change the given permissions after allowing it once.

Comment: I agree. A slightly alternative way would be to add a handler for #200 error (Requires extended permission) rather than sending the /me/permissions request each time. Not very elegant either but it's a workaround for a bug after all.

Answer (score 1):

If you make an API call to `/me/permissions` all permissions currently associated with the access token you're using will be returned

Comment: in this case FBSession.activeSession.permissions return me the list of permissions that i request but it is not updated when the session started.

Answer (score 0):

```
[FBSession.activeSession.permissions indexOfObject:@"publish_stream"] != NSNotFound
```

The code above is not the right way to check for write permissions.

Instead of that please try the following :

```
-(BOOL)hasWritePermissions{

    NSArray *permissiones = [FBSession activeSession].permissions;
    for (NSString *permission in permissiones) {

        if ([permission isEqualToString:@"publish_actions"]) {
            return YES;
        }
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: You could simplify it to, `[[FBSession activeSession].permissions containsObject:@"publish_actions"]` but the root of the problem is that the permissions list is cached.

Answer (score 0):

As @Zorayr said you can do as follows.

```
NSArray *permissions = FBSession.activeSession.permissions;
    if ([permissions containsObject:@"publish_actions"]) {
       [self performNextTestWithLastPostID:nil];
    } else {
        ...
}
```